# How to embed checkbox with label in Card Media?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I tried to code this thing. But the `CardMedia` will not go together with the checkbox. so responsive is a failure.

```
            <Card>
                <CardMedia
                    component='img'
                    alt=''
                    height='160'
                    image=''
                    title='Image'
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#DEDBDB',
                             position: 'relative' }}
                />
                {/*<input type='checkbox' id='select'*/}
                {/*       style={{ position: 'absolute', marginLeft: '20%', marginTop: '-2%'}}*/}
                {/*/>*/}
                {/*<label htmlFor='select'*/}
                {/*       style={{ position: 'absolute', marginLeft: '21%', marginTop: '-2.15%'}}*/}
                {/*>選択</label>*/}
                <Box mt={-6} ml={45}>
                    <span><Checkbox inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'uncontrolled-checkbox' }} /></span>
                </Box>
            </Card>
```

I tried also the `FormControlLabel` for this so that the label and checkbox will be together and style it with position: absolute and some margins so that the result will be like this.

But the problem is that it is not responsive and if using box label disappear.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, your problem is connected to the `zIndex` of the label in `FormControlLabel`. Infact, if you inspect the page you can see the label present on DOM but invisible (maybe because on `CardMedia` the image is always on top, but this is my personal opinion).

To solve this problem, you can override the style of the label associated to the `FormControlLabel`. [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-card-forked-ch75c?file=/src/App.js) is a codesandbox example.

At first I defined a `CustomCheckbox`:

```
const CustomCheckbox = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    // checkbox style example
    // color: "#000000"
    // '&$checked': {
    //     color: "#000000",
    // },
  },
  checked: {}
}))((props) => <Checkbox color="default" {...props} />);
```

Then, I used it into `Card`:

```
<Box mt={-6} ml={45}>
   <span>
      <FormControlLabel
         control={
            <CustomCheckbox
               checked={cheboxChecked}
               onChange={handleChange}
               name="toggleFavorite"
             />
          }
          label="Checkbox label"  // label value
          classes={{
             label: styles.formcontrollabel  // label class overriding
          }}
       />
    </span>
 </Box>
```

And finally in `makeStyles` I made the override:

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    formcontrollabel: {
      "&.MuiFormControlLabel-label": {
        zIndex: 1
      }
    }
  }));
```

The result is:

[image]

The label is responsive also (in this case "label" word goes on new line if you reduce screen width) as long as possible (if you continue to reduce screen width, label will be cutted). But this is normal (because you defined Box like `<Box mt={-6} ml={45}>`). If you don't like this behaviour, you could use a `Hidden` component to hidden checkbox and label if screen goes under a certain breakpoint like:

```
<Hidden smDown>  // if screen width goes under smDown breakpoint, the Hidden content will be hided
   ...
</Hidden>
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that I have to use useStyles for this.

Comment: No problem :) . Yes, I used it to make the customization to `.MuiFormControlLabel-label` (because to do this I need to call `makeStyles`)